# MYSQL Display column values only once from table

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I Have two tables by name invoice and invoice_product. To visiualize :

invoice table

```
Invoice_Number  Invoice_Date  Customer_Name  Total_Amount 

     1           2013-08-01        XYZ        10000
     2           2013-08-02        ABC         7000
     3           2013-08-03        DEF         4000
```

invoice_product table

```
Invoice_Number    Product_names     Price

       1              prd1          5000
       1              prd2          3000
       1              prd3          2000
       2              prd22         3000
       2              prd25         4000
       3              prd13         2500
       3              prd16         1500
```

I want to get the following output by combining both the tables.

```
Invoice_Number  Invoice_Date  Product_names Customer_Name  Total_Amount 

     1           2013-08-01        prd1          XYZ         10000
                                   prd2
                                   prd3

     2           2013-08-02        prd22         ABC         7000
                                   prd25

     3           2013-08-03        prd13         DEF         4000
                                   prd16
```

I tried the following query.

```
select Invoice_Number,Invoice_Date,Product,Customer_Name,Total_Amount from invoice,invoice_product where invoice.Invoice_Number=invoice_product.invoice_Number;
```

I am getting the following output.

```
Invoice_Number  Invoice_Date  Product_names Customer_Name  Total_Amount 

     1           2013-08-01        prd1          XYZ         10000
     1           2013-08-01        prd2          XYZ         10000
     1           2013-08-01        prd3          XYZ         10000

     2           2013-08-02        prd22         ABC         7000
     2           2013-08-02        prd25         ABC         7000

     3           2013-08-03        prd13         DEF         4000
     3           2013-08-03        prd16         DEF         4000
```

Shall I need to use anything like `Having,Distinct,Group By` in the query to get the desired output? I am newbie to mysql. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can do it in `php`. just do the manipulation during iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want only one row per invoice, but want each product listed, I would suggest using `GROUP_CONCAT()` function like this:

```
SELECT
  i.Invoice_Number AS Invoice_Number,
  i.Invoice_Date AS Invoice_Date,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ip.Product) AS products,
  i.Customer_Name AS Customer_Name,
  i.Total_Amount AS Total_Amount
FROM invoice AS i
INNER JOIN invoice_product AS ip
  ON i.Invoice_Number=ip.invoice_Number
GROUP BY i.Invoice_Number
```

By default `GROUP_CONCAT()` uses commas as separators between values so for `products` column you would get values like `prd1,prd2,prd3`. You can specify a different separator as desired.